# neo4j creating more relationships in one query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i want to create more replationships from one node in one query

```
MATCH (n:Type) WHERE n.user = "usr2" 
MATCH (p:Test) WHERE p.name = "test1"
CREATE (n)-[:CONTAINS {amount:5}]->(p)
MATCH (p1:Test) WHERE p1.name = "test2"
CREATE (n)-[:CONTAINS {amount:-7}]->(p1)
```

but im getting invalid syntax.

is there any other way than this?

```
MATCH (n:Type) WHERE n.user = "usr2"
MATCH (p:Test) WHERE p.name = "test1"
CREATE (n)-[:CONTAINS {amount:5}]->(p); 
MATCH (n:Type) WHERE n.user = "usr2" 
MATCH (p:Test) WHERE p1.name = "test2"
CREATE (n)-[:CONTAINS {amount:-7}]->(p);
```

Because this doesnt seems to be very efficient for lot of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, use WITH after create:

```
MATCH (n:Type) WHERE n.user = "usr2" 
MATCH (p:Test) WHERE p.name = "test1"
CREATE (n)-[:CONTAINS {amount:5}]->(p)
WITH n
MATCH (p1:Test) WHERE p1.name = "test2"
CREATE (n)-[:CONTAINS {amount:-7}]->(p1)
```

1. make sure to have an index/constraint on `:Type(user)` and `:Test(name)`
2. use parameters
3. use simple statements but many of them then cypher can cache the execution plans
4. execute many simple statements in a single http request with the cypher [transactional endpoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html)

Answer (score 2):

How about this? Matches up front and creates afterwards?

```
MATCH (n:Type) WHERE n.user = "usr2" 
MATCH (p:Test) WHERE p.name = "test1"
MATCH (p1:Test) WHERE p1.name = "test2"
CREATE n-[:CONTAINS {amount:5}]->p
CREATE n-[:CONTAINS {amount:-7}]->p1
```

Comment: For a more efficient way of loading multiple records check out ` LOAD CSV`.